# When installing updates, I do not get any progress indication

Tags: updates, lubuntu

Using Lubuntu, when I install updates, update manager simply closes out after I authenticate. There is no progress indicator to tell me when the update are completed. I used to get a terminal window that showed how the updates were progressing, but that has stopped. Anyway to get that original behavior back?

Comment: Lubuntu version?

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get update` from a terminal work?